# Alternating Harmonic Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Define a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ by the formula

$$a_n= \sum_{i=n}^\infty (-1)^{i-n} \dfrac{1}{i}$$

**Conjecture:** $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is decreasing sequence.

Can you prove it, or give a counter example?

*(Note that $a_n$ is positive)*

Answer (score 3):

If we rewrite

$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{n+k},$$

we obtain

$$\begin{align}
a_n - a_{n+1} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{n+k} - \frac{1}{n+1+k}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(n+k)(n+1+k)}\\
&> \frac{1}{n(n+1)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&> 0,
\end{align}$$

since $\dfrac{1}{(n+k)(n+1+k)}$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is decreasing:
\begin{align}
a_n-a_{n+1} &=
\sum_{i=n}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i-n}}{i}
-\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i-{n+1}}}{i}
=\sum_{i=n}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i-n}}{i}
-\sum_{i=n}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i-{n}}}{i+1} \\ &=\sum_{i=n}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i-{n}}}{i(i+1)}=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(n+2k)(n+2k+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+2k+1)(n+2k+2)}\right)>0.
\end{align}